# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\nu(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)^2$ for $s$ real

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, riemann-zeta, arithmetic-functions

**Note.** I have added some remarks at the end of my post regarding the mistakes in my argument.

The other day I proved that $\zeta(s)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu(n)n^{-s}$ for all $s\in\mathbb R,$ where $\nu(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n,$ however I'm not sure about my argument, which is the following (I'm sorry if I'm not seeing some trivial detail).

**Proposition.** Prove that if $s$ is a real number then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\nu(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)^2.$$

*Proof.* If $s\leqslant1$ the result is clear. Now assume $s>1.$ For each positive integer $n$ define $$f(n):=\sum_{d\mid n}\dfrac{\nu(d)}{d^s},$$ where the sum runs over all positive divisors of $n.$ Note that since the function $\nu(n)/n^s$ is multiplicative then $f$ is multiplicative; thus for a fixed $n$ we have $$f\left(\prod_{p\leqslant n}p^{\alpha_p}\right)=\prod_{p\leqslant n}f(p^{\alpha_p}),\tag1$$ where the products are taken over all positive primes not exceeding $n$ and where $\alpha_p:=\lfloor\log{n}/\log p\rfloor$ for each $p.$ Now fix $p.$ Clearly we have $$f(p^{\alpha_p})=\sum_{m=0}^{\alpha_p}\dfrac{m+1}{p^{ms}},$$ so if we set $t:=\alpha_p,$ $q:=p^s$ and $\sigma:=1+q^{-1}+\cdots+q^{-t}$ then we have $$\begin{aligned}
f(p^t)&=\sigma+(\sigma-1)+(\sigma-1-q^{-1})+\cdots+(\sigma-1-q^{-1}-\cdots-q^{1-t})\\\\&=(t+1)\sigma-t-(t-1)q^{-1}-\cdots-(t-(t-1))q^{1-t}\\\\&=(t+1)\sigma-t(\sigma-q^{-t})+q^{-1}\left(1+2q^{-2}+\cdots+(t-1)^{q^{2-t}}\right)\\\\&=\sigma+tq^{-t}+q^{-1}\left(f(p^t)-tq^{-t}-(t+1)q^{-t}\right)\end{aligned}$$ and hence $$f(p^t)(1-q^{-1})^2=1+tq^{-t}+2tq^{-t-2}-2q^{-t-1}-3tq^{-t-1}-q^{-t-2}$$ but if $p$ is fixed and we let $n\to\infty$ then each of the terms to the right of $1$ in the last expression goes to $0$ (as a consequence of the binomial theorem) so $f(p^t)\to(1-q^{-1})^{-2}=(1-p^{-s})^{-2}$ which by $(1)$ implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\prod_{p\leqslant n}p^{\alpha_p}\right)=\prod_p(1-p^{-s})^{-2}=\zeta(s)^2\tag2$$ and this together with $$\sum_{k\leqslant n}\dfrac{\nu(k)}{k^s}\leqslant f\left(\prod_{p\leqslant n}p^{\alpha_p}\right)=\sum_{d\mid\prod\limits_{p\leqslant n}p^{\alpha_p}}\dfrac{\nu(d)}{d^s}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{\nu(k)}{k^s}$$ implies that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\nu(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)^2,$$ as desired. $\square$

**THE PROBLEM IS** is it right to conclude that if $n\to\infty$ then $\alpha_p\to\infty$ for each prime $p$?

**EDIT.** A few minutes ago (like two hours ago) I realized what was wrong in my proof. None of the answers I received was helpful in that particular sense (althoug they were helpful). First, let me clarify why I say that the case $s\leqslant1$ trivial: I assume (maybe my assumption is completely incorrect) that $\zeta(s)^2=(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s})^2.$ Now let me clarify where is the main mistake in my argument: of course for a fixed prime $p$ we have $\alpha_p=\lfloor\log{n}/\log{p}\rfloor\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty,$ however, this doesn't necessarily implie that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\prod_{p\leqslant n}p^{\alpha_p}\right)=\prod_p(1-p^{-s})^{-2}.$ As an easy example of a case in which this same argument can be (wrongly) applied is in the sequence $\{\sqrt[n]{n!}\}.$ We could, using the same (wrong) reasoning I used and fix $m,$ with $1\leqslant m\leqslant n.$ Then we observe that $\sqrt[n]{m}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ and conclude (wrongly) that therefore $\sqrt[n]{n!}\to1.$

Comment: Why is the result clear if $s \le 1$?

Comment: @Unit because $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s}\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\nu(k)k^{-s}$ and if $n\to\infty$ and $s\leqslant1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s}\to\infty$ and also $(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-s})^2\to\infty$

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. Let me use the notation $\sigma_0(n) = \nu(n)$. For $Re(s) > 1$ where it converges, the proof is that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converges absolutely, therefore $\zeta(s)^2 = \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty (mk)^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{mk = n} n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sigma_0(n)$ by a simple change of order of summation. Note how it proves that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \nu(n)$ converges absolutely for $Re(s) > 1$.

Comment: Now for proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sigma_0(n)$ diverges for $Re(s)< 1$, you have to say that for real $s$ :  $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s} \sigma_0(n) \ge \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}> \frac{N^{1-s}}{1-s}$ so it diverges, and use the concept of [abscissa convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence) for extending it to $s \not \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl and for $Re(s)< 1$, $\zeta(s) \ne \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ ($\zeta(s)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$, whereas the series diverges)

Comment: Thank you, although I wanted some corrections regarding my specific argument, it's always good to see a shorter and more elegant one! (and also, I apologize if I didn't see it, but it was MAYBE because of my lack of knowledge). Anyway, than you!

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote, and why your consider $\sum_{d | n} \sigma_0(d) d^{-s}$. There is only one proof, and it is the one we wrote. **And again, $\zeta(s)$ is analytic on $Re(s) < 1$, it is not given anymore by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$. For $Re(s) > 0$ a valid representation is $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$**

Comment: You already said that. Also, you should note that 5 hours have past since I wrote the last comment. I edited my answer pointing out the mistakes I have. Also, I think that if you read my (completely wrong) argument you will understand why I used that sum (because of what I tried to do). Now, I'm not saying that you are wrong so stop being so aggressive. One of the aims of this site is to help unexperienced people like me. I'm just an undergraduate who stopped studying completely for   almost 2 years and now I'm returning.

Comment: I'm not agressive, the problem is that your edit shows you didn't understand how the proof is simple, and even worse, you didn't remove "If s⩽1 the result is clear" which is a huge nonsense

Comment: And you should read again my 1st comment, where the main argument is the *absolute convergence*. The absolute convergence is also the main argument for proving that $\zeta(s) = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k \ge 1}p^{-sk}) = \prod_p (1-p^{-s})^{-s}$ for $Re(s) > 1$

Answer (score 2):

For $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $s>\max\{1,r+1\}$ we have

$$\zeta(s)\zeta(s-r)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty\frac{1}{t^s}\sum\limits_{d=1}^\infty\frac{1}{d^{s-r}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\sum\limits_{t\cdot d=n}d^r$$

and with $r:=0$ we get the formula for $\zeta^2(s)$.

Comment: As I said in the comments: Thank you, although I wanted some corrections regarding my specific argument, it's always good to see a shorter and more elegant one! (and also, I apologize if I didn't see it, but it was MAYBE because of my lack of knowledge).. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl nobody understood what you wrote. In particular considering $\sum_{d | n} \sigma_0(d) d^{-s}$ is a non-sense, and of course $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{d | n} \sigma_0(d) d^{-s}$ diverges

Comment: @user1952009 why is that so? (why is it non-sense). I appreciate all the corrections you can give

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl how is it related to showing that $\zeta(s)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sigma_0(n)$ for $Re(s) > 1$ ?

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl Now if you want a multiplicative proof, show that $\sigma_0(n)$ is multiplicative, and that $1+\sum_{k \ge 1}p^{-sk}\sigma_0(p^k) = (1+\sum_{k \ge 1}p^{-sk})^2$

Comment: Well, I wanted to write as many details as possible (without writing a lot of unnecessary details), but I think I need to work on my writing.

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl No, you need to work on your main argument